# Feature: photo tagging as part of html code

Tags: html, image, tags

Currently, in html, for images, we have attributes like: [alt,align,border,crossorigin,height,hspace,ismap,longdesc,src,usemap,vspace,width].
Source: [HTML img tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp#gsc.tab=0).
 I was thinking about embedding photo tagging feature in html-level support itself. 
Like, for example, currently, in the context of Facebook website, images can be tagged. 
What if, there are zillions of images outside of facebook and there is a need for tagging for photos? 
Can anyone share pointers to start in this direction? 
This idea occurred when I was browsing this link: [76 Powerful Thoughts from Paul Graham](http://www.rosshudgens.com/thoughts-from-paul-graham/) and I hovered my mouse over the first pic in the link. 
If you hover mouse over any face, it shows: Paul Graham. 
But I was interested in knowing, who were the other people in the same photo. 
As of now, I don't have ideas how to get started on this. Can anyone share their thoughts?. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to  create it in the html-level? Why dont just using javascript and its libraries for it?

Comment: Using Javascript and its libraries or plugins will be localized to that website. But, what if this image is transferred across systems. We still want to retain that tagged information for that image. Here, too html will be localized. I agree. I need to tag this question properly.

Comment: Then the only solution is to add that information in the image itself, which is start talking about a new image format with tag info. I wonder then how would you be able to tag someone in the picture... You will need to create another program to deal with that :)

Comment: I agree. :) I have ideas, like: coordinates in the image mapped to an arraylist of Names( names of people )